Want to get count of records
I have total 3 tables.
CalendarData, HotelResource, HotelResourcesBookings.
In CalendarData I am storing Dates for each month, below I am sharing few example records.
In HotelResource I am storing Hotel names, below I am sharing few example records.
In HotelResourcesBookings I am storing booking data with Date and HotelResourceId,below I am sharing few example records.
Here in HotelResourcesBookings table I can have multiple bookings for same day and for same hotel id. You can see in below table for hotelId 2 I have two bookings for 5-Dec.
So what I want is count of bookings for that date, for example I need 2 in that date.
Right now I have written query in that way, so it will return data for whole month dates for Dec month with booking ids, Now in that query I want to add count.
CalendarData example :



Id
Date




1
2024-12-01 00:00:00.000


2
2024-12-02 00:00:00.000


3
2024-12-03 00:00:00.000



HotelResource example :



Id
Name




1
Hotel1


2
Hotel2



HotelResourcesBookings example :



Id
HotelId
Date




1
1
2024-12-01 00:00:00.000


2
1
2024-12-02 00:00:00.000


3
2
2024-12-05 00:00:00.000


4
2
2024-12-05 00:00:00.000



I want following output



Date
HotelId
Name
HotelResourceId
Count




2024-12-01 00:00:00.000
1
Hotel1
1
1


2024-12-02 00:00:00.000
1
Hotel1
2
1


2024-12-03 00:00:00.000
1
Hotel1
NULL
0


2024-12-04 00:00:00.000
1
Hotel1
NULL
0


2024-12-05 00:00:00.000
1
Hotel1
NULL
0


2024-12-01 00:00:00.000
2
Hotel2
NULL
0


2024-12-02 00:00:00.000
2
Hotel2
NULL
0


2024-12-03 00:00:00.000
2
Hotel2
NULL
0


2024-12-04 00:00:00.000
2
Hotel2
NULL
0


2024-12-05 00:00:00.000
2
Hotel2
3
2


2024-12-05 00:00:00.000
2
Hotel2
4
2




What is the calendar table good for? And do you want results for particular dates, a certain month maybe? Or do you want something related to today? E.g., today plus the 50 last days? Or something depending on the data in the table, like the newest date in the table and 20 days back from there?

@ThorstenKettner I am trying to fetch data for whole December month. So it will give me record for each date of month for each hotels.

What DBMS are you using? When tagging a request with sql, you are asked to also tag it with your DBMS. In Oracle, for instance, you would probably use a partitioned outer join for this kind of task. As far as I know, though, Oracle is the only DBMS supporting this kind of join. So we need to know the DBMS in order to give an appropriate answer.

I am using sql.

SQL is just the general language. But different products (database management systems = DBMS), like MySQL or SQL Server or PostgreSQL or Oracle or ... have different dialects of SQL. A syntax valid in one DBMS may not work in another.

And there is nothing dynamic about the query? You want December 2024, and if in some future you want another month, you will write a query for that other month? And you want all dates of a month or only those dates available in the calendar table?

Yes I will make query dynamic and pass month and year as parameter and fetch dates for that months

Okay. So again: what DBMS are you using? Is it MySQL or SQLite or SQL Server or what else?

I am using SQL Server

I created a fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/QFV39lAU

Note that tables have rows, not records.


You can CROSS JOIN Calendar Date and HotelResource to get all combination of dates and hotels.

Then LEFT JOIN Bookings to get the distribution of booking.

Partition by date and hotel id is used to get number of bookings per hotel for each date.


Fiddle
SELECT 
    cd.Date,
    hr.Id AS HotelId,
    hr.Name,
    hrb.Id AS HotelResourceId,
    COUNT(hrb.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY cd.Date, hr.Id) AS Count
FROM 
    CalendarData cd
CROSS JOIN 
    HotelResource hr
LEFT JOIN 
    HotelResourcesBookings hrb
    ON cd.Date = hrb.Date
    AND hr.Id = hrb.HotelId
ORDER BY 
    cd.Date, hr.Id, hrb.Id;

Output


Why did you add 2 records to the CalendarData example table?

you mean why 5 records? I would assume it would contain all day of a year as per the name.I just added 5 records as per the sample data talked about 1st through 5th december

Note tables have rows and columns, not records or fields.

Start with creating the result rows that you want. That is: hotels X days. A cross join. Then outer join the bookings that you have and aggregate and count.
DECLARE @year INT = 2024;
DECLARE @month INT = 12;

with
  days as
  (
    select cd.date
    from calendardata cd
    where cd.date >= datefromparts(@year, @month, 1)
      and cd.date <  dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(@year, @month, 1))
  )
select hr.id, hr.name, days.date, count(hrb.id) 
from hotelresource hr
cross join days
left outer join hotelresourcesbookings hrb on hrb.hotelid = hr.id
                                          and hrb.date = days.date    
group by hr.id, hr.name, days.date
order by hr.id, days.date;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/tw6jlAIy (Thanks to @Bart McEndree)

Must declare the scalar variable "@year"

Your output has 6 rows. Hajmol expects 11 rows.

@Bart McEndree: I don't know how complete the sample data is. They said they wanted a particular month. I asked if the result was to be limited to the days in the calendar table and got no answer.
